# How to tell what types any map consists of

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to be able to tell if a type in a `std::map` consists of a `std::map` itself. My scenario looks like the following:

```
template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
void mapPrint(std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> m) {
}
```

How would I check if either Key or T is a `std::map`? Say I send:

```
std::map<std::map<int,int>, int> m;
```

To this function. Is it possible to recursively iterate through all the types until only trivial types are found?

Edit:
This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A {
  public:
    void testFunc(int) {}
};

class B {
  public:
    void testFunc(int) {}
};

class C {
  public:
    void notTestFunc() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct hasTestFunc {
    typedef char (& yes)[1];
    typedef char (& no)[2];

    template <typename C> static yes comp(decltype(&C::testFunc));
    template <typename> static no comp(...);

    static bool const value = sizeof(comp<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
void mapPrint(std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator> m) {
    std::cout << hasTestFunc<Key>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << hasTestFunc<T>::value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::map<std::map<A,A>, A> m;
  mapPrint(m);
  return 0;
}
```

I want the output of this program to be:

> 1 1 1

Right now it is:

> 0 1

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, it is possible to do that, using specialization and some helper glue code. The exact details depend on specific details, i.e., what exactly is the expected result in such a case? `std::tuple<int,int,int>`? Which one of the `int`s is which. Or, just an `int` and another `int`? Same question. In order to answer something like this you have to: provide more detail, and show your work so far. If you are not familiar with these advance template concepts, like specialization, you need to learn them first otherwise you will likely not understand the answer at all.

Comment: You will need to further explain why exactly you "want the output" to be that. There are three fundamental types in `std::map<std::map<A,A>, A>`, three non maps, three `A`s; and also two `std::map`s, so the output should include three 0s and two 1s, if everything is checked recursively.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my post, I want the output to be: 1 1 1, I only want to check if the type has the member function testFunc if the type is NOT a container. If it is a container, I want to check if the type the container is consisting of has the member function testFunc.

Comment: A "container" is something very different than "std::map", as the example is shown. This should be pretty easy for a map, but becomes more complicated if an arbitrary container needs to be checked. The key to getting a good answer on stackoverflow.com is to be able to ask a concise, precise question. If you can't quite ask the right question, you can't expect anyone to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to do partial specialization of the function `mapPrint`. That is however not possible so we need to fall back to partial specialization of structs. (Note, I renamed your `T` to `Value`, for my own convenience)

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    struct printerHasTestFunc
    {
        void operator()()
        {
            std::cout << hasTestFunc<T>::value << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
    struct printerHasTestFunc<std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>>
    {
        void operator()()
        {
            printerHasTestFunc<Key>{}();
            printerHasTestFunc<Value>{}();
        }
    };
}
```

now we can introduce simple wrapper function to *call* the struct.

```
template<typename T>
void printHasTestFunc()
{
    detail::printerHasTestFunc<T>{}();
}
```

And let the partial specialization do the magic.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Value>>>
void mapPrint(std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator> m) {
    printHasTestFunc<Key>();
    printHasTestFunc<Value>();
}
```

[Try it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee1fe73d724b8245).

#### Edit (C++17, more straightforward solution)

In c++17, we can take advantage of `constexpr if`. But first, we need a trait to check if a type is `std::map`

```
template <typename>
struct is_std_map : std::false_type{};

template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Less, typename Compare>
struct is_std_map<std::map<Key, Value, Less, Compare>> : std::true_type{};
```

Now a simple function, that will recurse on maps

```
template<typename T>
void printHasTestFunc()
{
    if constexpr (is_std_map<T>::value)
    {
        printHasTestFunc<typename T::key_type>();
        printHasTestFunc<typename T::mapped_type>();
    }
    else
        std::cout << hasTestFunc<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

And `mapPrint` can just call this function.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Value>>>
void mapPrint(std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator> m) {
    printHasTestFunc<std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>>();
}
```

[See this live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2c97b87804f6ba2).

Answer (score 1):

With some overloads, you might do:

```
template <typename> struct Tag {};

template <typename T>
void TagPrint(Tag<T>) {
    std::cout << hasTestFunc<T>::value << std::endl;
}

template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
void TagPrint(Tag<std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>>) {
        TagPrint(Tag<Key>{});    
        TagPrint(Tag<T>{});    
}

template <typename Key, typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
void mapPrint(const std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>&) {
    return TagPrint(Tag<std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbdf3faa9c45746c)